# Why can't JSON.parse() parse what date.toJSON() creates?

Tags: javascript, json

*Tested using chrome Canary*

I can convert a date to JSON:

```
> (new Date()).toJSON()
  "2012-05-03T22:27:30.530Z"
```

I can convert it back to a Date:

```
> typeof (new Date("2012-05-03T22:27:30.530Z"))
  object
```

Why can't I parse it as a Date using JSON.parse()? JSON.parse returns a string, not a Date:

```
> JSON.parse('{"DateValue":"2012-05-03T22:27:30.530Z"}').DateValue
 "2012-05-03T22:27:30.530Z"
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to return a Date object, if the value associated with "DateValue" key is not a Date object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because a Date is not a valid type in JSON.  JSON only knows about strings, numbers, booleans, arrays, and generic objects (associative arrays/hashes/maps/dictionaries/pick-your-favorite-name).  When you convert anything else to JSON, you get one of the above - which means if you want to get the "something else" back out as the type it started as, the receiver has to do some extra work to recreate it.

There are JSON libraries that abstract that work away, and include an extra attribute indicating what class something is, so if the receiver is using the same library they'll get that type back, but that's still the same work, just hidden by the library.

Comment: Are there any JSON libraries like that, that work between Javascript and Python? I dumbly just spent two days writing a buggy one when it sounds like I could have just downloaded one :(

Comment: The libraries that do actual object serialization with JSON, at least the ones I can think of, are designed for use within a single language.  For communication between languages you usually go with simpler messages instead of serializing complex custom objects.

Comment: I did it so I could send dates back and forth without having to expressly know which fields were supposed to be dates when de-serializing.

Answer (score 3):

Because in the JSON, the date *is* a string, in the same way `new Date("2012-05-03T22:27:30.530Z")` parses a string. You're expecting JavaScript to know that the string in the JSON is a date.

You need to pass the JSON parsed string to the date object to get a date back out:

```
var date = new Date(JSON.parse('{"DateValue":"2012-05-03T22:27:30.530Z"}').DateValue);
```

Comment: @lonesomeday Not really. Even if there was such a datatype, the value of "DataType" is still just a string.

Comment: If you want a parser to do this in general, you're going to need to make your own conventions on top of JSON, like "If an object in my JSON has a `__type__` key, when parsing it, call the corresponding constructor with the value of the `__value__` key." Then you'd need to represent dates as `'{"__type__":"Date", "__value__":"2012-05-03T22:27:30.530Z "}`, and do something besides `.toJSON()` to format dates like that.

Comment: @Imp I think what @lonesomeday meant was that if there was a date type in JSON, then `.toJSON` would respect that.

Comment: @btown Precisely that – thanks for phrasing it better than I.

Comment: @btown Sure :) What I meant is that if there actually was a Date type in JSON, it would be somehow distinguished from a string. So the value discussed above, being of the form `"[^"]*"`, would still be a string.

Answer (score 0):

The `.toJSON` method is only there to return a value that can be representated in JSON. Yet JSON does not know about data types, and is not possible to store object instance information (like the prototype) in a JSON string.

So, the toJSON method of Date could return a number (e.g. the Unix timestamp), a plain object with properties representing year, month, day etc. (not so good because not parsable with the Date constructor) or - what happens to be - a string, in here the ISO time format. With that, you can use `new Date(JSON.parse(stringified_date))` to create a new Date object.

If you would `delete Date.prototype.toJSON;`, `JSON.stringify(new Date)` would result in `"{}"`.